# Is there a way to specify paste directly after right mouse click in AutoHotkey v2?

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey

Is there a way to specify paste directly after right mouse click in AutoHotkey v2?

Current code

```
<^z::Send, {RButton}{p}
```

Problem ／
There are multiple shortcuts (p) in the right-clicked menu

Other ／
The reason why Ctrl+V is not used is because I want the paste destination to be the selected folder.
Ctrl+V can only paste to the current folder.

---

Added on December 18, 2023.

**Directory Structure**

/img/result/2023/

/img/result/2024/

**Operation Procedure**

1. Cut out hoge.jpg
2. In the /result/ folder, select the /2023/ folder with the mouse and paste it into the /2023/ folder.

**Desired operation**

If I right-click the mouse and paste, I get /img/result/2023/hoge.jpg,

**What I don't want to do**

But if I press Ctrl + V to paste, it becomes /img/result/hoge.jpg.

When right-clicking in the folder with jpg, "Play with Windows Media Player (P)" is displayed, and "Paste (P)" conflicts with (P).

Comment: Mixing shortcuts (like CTRL+V), and their (assigned) behavior is not the way to describe a good question. When doing a rightclick on my system I (almost) never get a menu, from where are you doing this right-click?   Please read: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and do share more details (remember we cannot see what you are seeing on your screen....)

Comment: Added to the text.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps instead of using the built-in Paste behavior, you would be better off using AutoHotkey to its fullest to perform the entire operation without emulating keyboard presses.

I can't be sure what your entire operation will entail based on the details given. For example, you did not indicate where hoge.jpg exists currently. Also, how should it determine whether it ends up in the 2023 or 2024? These things could be further automated instead of relying on the current state of Windows Explorer.

In any case, in my example, I'll show one way of doing what I believe you're asking, but there are probably better ways depending on what your situation fully entails. That can only be appropriately answered if adequate information is provided.

```
<^z::
{
    ; get the HWND of the current active Windows Explorer window
    If (!(WinHWND := WinActive("ahk_class CabinetWClass")) &&
            !(WinHWND := WinActive("ahk_class ExploreWClass"))) {
        ; if no Explorer window is active, cancel and do nothing
        return
    }
    ; get the Window title to ensure proper tab
    ; (this logic can be skipped if not using tabbed Explorer)
    winTitle := WinGetTitle("ahk_id " WinHWND)
    for window in ComObject("Shell.Application").Windows {
        ; The following works for getting the active window (and tab) for
        ; Explorer in Windows 10/11, but it can mess up if two tabs in the same
        ; Explorer window have the same window title in Windows 11
        if (window.hwnd == WinHWND && window.LocationName == winTitle) {
            ; get the COM Object of the FIRST selected item in Explorer
            selectedFolder := window.Document.SelectedItems().Item(0)
            ; get the full path of the item above
            selectedFolderPath := selectedFolder.Path

            ; Some other useful variables, albeit unnecessary in this example:
            currentDirectory := window.Document.Folder.Self.Path
            selectedFolderName := selectedFolder.Name ; just the folder name itself

            ; The active window was found, so stop looping the Explorer windows
            break
        }
    }
    ; A_Clipboard contains the full path of the file in the clipboard (cut/copy)
    ; Move the file in the clipboard to the first folder selected in Explorer
    FileMove A_Clipboard, selectedFolderPath
}
```